# Invoking task manager via Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to invoke an exe (like task manager,notepad) after clicking on a link in google chrome extension (javascript code) or due to security constraints that is not at all possible ? I do not want to use background or content scripts. I am able to do perform other actions like opening links, reading API response etc which i require for my utility in javascript.

Getting following error -
popup.html:20 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Thanks
Jaideep

Comment: The error you mention has nothing to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: Sure Xan, the error was due to trying to invoke of exe in the javascript function (ActiveX also does not work in Chrome), it would be great if you can tell if there is a way to perform the action after reading the problem statement before voting down the question?I am a beginner in Javascript.please ignore the error

Comment: trying with Native messaging,"chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage". hopefully should solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to invoke the task manager by setting the manifest file separately as

{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}

and adding the registry 
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Admin\manifest.json" /f

and javascript code for message API